# Gradle Build Failed : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In Android Studio (Version 2.3), When i try to build (or clean) any project I am getting this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MJOm.jpg)

How to solve this problem? I have searched a lot but could not be able to find any solution. Please help.

**UPDATE:**

*app:gradle code:*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.net23.fahimabrar.teacherassistant"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Post your `app:gradle` code

Comment: Edited. Please check. @Srihari

Comment: It is happening even if i create a new project.

Comment: Malformed exception is thrown when an input byte sequence is not legal for given charset, or an input character sequence is not a legal sixteen-bit Unicode sequence. Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/MalformedInputException.html

Comment: Do you have any idea what can I do about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File -> Project Structure -> select "project" TAB ,make sure that every module's "Build Tools Version" in your project is same  to each other.(my version is 25.0.0)